# Explain me some pieces of the following JSP code :

Tags: java, jsp

I am unable to get a piece of code in the following JSP code ( commented as d1, d2, d3, d4):

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" errorPage="/MyError.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>LoginProcess</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
      Connection conn = null;
      String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
      String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
      try
      {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      }
      catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
      {
        out.println("Error(class):"+e);
      }
      try
      {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studentdb","root","mysql");
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from studentdb.userdetails where uname=? and pass=?");
        stmt.setString(1, uname);
        stmt.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if(!rs.next())
                {
                  out.println("username or password is incorrect");
    %>     <%--d1--%>
      Try Again:<%@include file="Login.html" %> <%--d2--%>
      </body>   <%--d3--%>
      </html>    <%--d4--%>
     <%        
         return;
        } //if
      } //try-sql
      catch(SQLException e)
      {
        out.println("Error(SQL):" + e);
      }
      finally
       {
         conn.close();
       }

    %>
    This is Home Page<br>
    Welcome,<b> <%= uname%></b>
</body>
```

the following are  appearing in an if block which I am not getting why and how do they work , I know the meaning of <%@include file="Login.jsp"> and selective tags but not I am getting how are they workign here.

```
   %>     <%--d1--%>                                                          
  Try Again:<%@include file="Login.html" %> <%--d2--%>                      
  </body>   <%--d3--%>                                                       
  </html>    <%--d4--%>                                             
 <%
```

(the body and html tags are not appearing in the above piece of code).

Comment: you missed the `return`. if the query returns nothing, the "try again" form is displayed and then `return`, otherwise the normal page footer gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if(!rs.next())`, try using `if(rs.isBeforeFirst())`. If `rs.isBeforeFirst()` is `false`, then you have no records.